# Are Fully Convolutional Neural Network (FCN) just normal ConvNets?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution, image-segmentation

I was reading the paper [Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4038) and on section 3 they introduce the notation for what they call a Fully Convolutional Neural Network (FCN). Are they just describing normal ConvNets? I find their notation confusing specially the following one:

$$ f_{ks} \circ g_{k's'} = (f \circ g)_{k' + (k-1)s', s s'}$$

I find that notation confusing since they don't define what $g$ is or any of its input arguments (k' & s'). The accompanying text is also confusing:

> While a general deep net computes a general nonlinear
>   function, a net with only layers of this form computes a
>   nonlinear filter, which we call a deep filter or fully convolutional network. An FCN naturally operates on an input of
>   any size, and produces an output of corresponding (possibly
>   resampled) spatial dimensions.

Are they just trying to use their own notation to say "here is what convnets are"?

Comment: an fcn is a convolutional network with no fully connected layers at the end